# C# ToDictionary get Anonymous Type value before C # 7

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

Hello here is how i get value from dictionary myage value after C# 7

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<User> userlist = new List<User>();
        User a = new User();
        a.name = "a";
        a.surname = "asur";
        a.age = 19;

        User b = new User();
        b.name = "b";
        b.surname = "bsur";
        b.age = 20;

        userlist.Add(a);
        userlist.Add(b);

        var userlistdict = userlist.ToDictionary(x => x.name,x=> new {x.surname,x.age });

        if(userlistdict.TryGetValue("b", out var myage)) //myage

        Console.WriteLine(myage.age);

    }  
}
public class User {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Okey result is:20

But Before C# 7 how can i get myage value from dictionary. I could't find any other way.Just i found declare myage in trygetvalue method.

Comment: Your best bet is to not use an anonymous class in the dictionary either make the value type of the dictionary `User` or use something like `Tuple<string, int>` instead.

Comment: value = userlistdict["b"]. This is the way we get dictionary value when we have key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three options:

First, you could write an extension method like this:

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key)
{
    TValue value;
    dictionary.TryGetValue(dictionary, out value);
    return value;
}
```

Then call it as:

```
var result = userlist.GetValueOrDefault("b");
if (result != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Second, you could use `var` with `out` by providing a dummy value:

```
var value = new { surname = "", age = 20 };
if (userlist.TryGetValue("b", out value))
{
    ...
}
```

Or as per comments:

```
var value = userlist.Values.FirstOrDefault();
if (userlist.TryGetValue("b", out value))
{
    ...
}
```

Third, you could use `ContainsKey` first:

```
if (userlist.ContainsKey("b"))
{
    var result = userlist["b"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: To avoid having to match the dummy value up perfectly, you could just get *a* value from the dictionary, say for example by doing `userlist.Value.FirstOrDefault()` so that if the anonymous type changes you don't have to also change how you initialize `value`.

Comment: As you do not need instance of anonymous type, but only type itself, you can prepend expression with `true ? null :` to get `null` of anonymous type. `true ? null : userlist.Values.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to store the `User` object as the dictionary item value instead of the anonymous type and then you can declare the type first and use that in the `TryGetValue`.

```
var userlistdict = userlist.ToDictionary(x => x.name, x =>  x );

User user;
if (userlistdict.TryGetValue("b",  out user))
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.surname);
    Console.WriteLine(user.age);
}
```

The first line of creating the Dictionary from the list  is same as

```
 var userlistdict = userlist.ToDictionary(x => x.name);
```

Comment: There's no need for an identity projection as the second argument to `ToDictionary`.  Just don't provide a second argument at all if you want to use the source item as the value.

Comment: That is correct. I explicitly specified it to highlight my point ( use User object as the value of the KeyValuePair item).